# ListShardMap. UpdateMapping throws an exception LockOwnerId Cannot be Null

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-elastic-scale

I tried different ways and googled a lot for the error but no luck so far.

I am trying to make a function which can update an existing shard mapping but I get the following exception.

```
Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.ShardManagementException: Store Error: Error 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure __ShardManagement.spBulkOperationShardMappingsLocal, Line 98, Message: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LockOwnerId', table 'TEST-POS.__ShardManagement.ShardMappingsLocal'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Though I created Create Shard and Delete Shard functions and they are working fine. But I get the above error while updating or creating a mapping.

Following is my code:

```
                PointMapping<int> pointMapping;
                bool mappingExists = _listShardMap.TryGetMappingForKey(9, out pointMapping);
                if (mappingExists)
                {
                    var shardLocation = new ShardLocation(NewServerName, NewDatabaseName);
                    Shard _shard;
                    bool shardExists =
                    _listShardMap.TryGetShard(shardLocation, out _shard);

                    if (shardExists)
                    {
                        var token = _listShardMap.GetMappingLockOwner(pointMapping);
                        var mappingUpdate = new PointMappingUpdate { Shard = _shard, Status = MappingStatus.Online };
                        var newMapping = _listShardMap.UpdateMapping(_listShardMap.MarkMappingOffline(pointMapping), mappingUpdate, token);
                    }
                }
```

I get the same error either I supply the token or not. Then I also tried to supply token in this way MappingLockToken.Create(), but then I get different error that correct token was not provided. It is also obvious because token is different.

```
    _listShardMap.UpdateMapping(offlineMapping, mappingUpdate, MappingLockToken.Create());

Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.ShardManagementException: Mapping referencing shard '[DataSource=cps-pos-test-1.database.windows.net Database=Live_MSA_Test_Cloud]' belonging to shard map 'ClientIDShardMap' is locked and correct lock token is not provided. Error occurred while executing procedure
```

I also checked the LockOwnerId in the [__ShardManagement].[ShardMappingsGlobal] table in the database and this is the ID = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

I though I am getting null insertion error because token Id is zero, so I updated it manually to 451a4da0-e3d4-42ac-bdc3-5b57022693d0 in database by executing an update query. But it did not work and I get the same Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LockOwnerId' error.

I am also facing the same Null error while creating a new mapping and I do not see in the code where to provide a token while creating a mapping. Following is code.

```
PointMappingCreationInfo<int> newMappingInfo = new PointMappingCreationInfo<int>(10, newShard, MappingStatus.Online);
                        var newMapping = _listShardMap.CreatePointMapping(newMappingInfo);
```

I searched it a lot on google and downloaded some sample applications as well, but I am not able to find the solution. I will highly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: `ShardMappingsLocal` is defined here: https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/blob/master/Src/ElasticScale.Client/ShardManagement/Scripts/CreateShardMapManagerLocal.cs#L54 I notice that is has default constraint that should make it non-null. 

It looks like the insert it happening at https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/blob/master/Src/ElasticScale.Client/ShardManagement/Scripts/CreateShardMapManagerLocal.cs#L985 . `LockOwnerId` is not specified here, so it should be getting default value.

Can you check if your ShardMappingsLocal.LockOwnerId column is somehow missing this default?

Comment: For example, looking at the `__ShardManagement.ShardMappingsLocal` table in SSMS I have a default constraint `DF__ShardMapp__LockO__3B75D760`. The last part is generated so it may be different for you.